# Blender: Multiple Animations

Tags: animation

I have a problem, I have 4 distinct objects, I need to make 2 animations, in which these 4 objects perform a specific movement for each animation, afterwards I have to export it to FBX and take it to Unity, what I expect is to have the model comprising 4 distinct objects and the 2 animations.

But I don't know how to do that, how do I make an animation where all 4 distinct objects move, how do I make 2 of them?